# Ruby/Selenium value into array

Tags: arrays, ruby, selenium

I need some help in Ruby/Selenium

i have a few elements on page like this:

```
<a class="Name" title="Migel" href="/profiles/users/_1324567980000000c/">Migel</a>
```

i'd like give HREF string value into array.

when i use "find_element" - ALL OK:

```
profile = driver.find_element(:xpath, "****").attribute ('href')
```

but page contains a lot of such elements, and i try to use

```
profile_array = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "lbuh-bluh").attribute ('href')
```

naturally that `attribute ('href')` dont work with array.
how can I do in this case?

in general, my task in implementing "random click" on page and i want collect all "href" elements which i need into array, and then realize something like this:

`array[srtring1, string2....stringN].sample.click` (schematically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would just mapping over elements and get href attribute be sufficient?

```
profile_array = driver
  .find_elements(:xpath, "lbuh-bluh")
  .map { |el| el.attribute('href') }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I earlier use .map with "find_element" hahaha! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is some sort of parsing html with Ruby, if this is the case why dont you use the [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) gem, lets say you have something like:

```
 <div id="funstuff">
      <p>Here are some entertaining links:</p>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube</a></li>
         <li><a data-category="news" href="http://reddit.com">Reddit</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://kathack.com/">Kathack</a></li>
         <li><a data-category="news" href="http://www.nytimes.com">New York Times</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Which is the content of a file called lets say: `selenium.html` located at your Desktop: `C:\Desktop\selenium.html`

here is the ruby code that handels that:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("C:\Desktop\selenium.html"))
    links = page.css("a")
    profile_array = []
     links.each{|ref| profile_array << ref["href"] }

    puts profile_array

 =>http://youtube.com
 =>http://reddit.com
 =>http://kathack.com/
 =>http://www.nytimes.com
```